# What to do with water-damaged touchscreen on ipod touch nano?

Tags: ipod-touch, damage, ipod-nano, touchscreen

Eight years ago I was gifted an ipod touch nano (generation 7, A1446). A few days later, I forgot it in my shirt, which went through a regular washing machine cycle. Surprisingly, the ipod still works: It charges the battery, it displays icons and streams music - but the touchscreen doesn't react at all. I just found it in a forgotten drawer when house cleaning.

Can the screen be repaired, preferably by someone who is fearless but has very moderate hardware and repair skills?

Or is there any other way than touch by which I can operate the device?

Meanwhile I found that I can buy LCD replacement and LCD plus digitizer replacement parts. Should I assume that the digitizer is broken?

Comment: It is best to have it repaired by an Apple-authorized service provider

Comment: While obviously having it repaired by an Apple-authorised service provider is the safest option, it's also ridiculously expensive of course and not what I believe @berndbausch is looking for.

Comment: Ifixit gave this product a 5/10 repairability score: https://nl.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod+Nano+7th+Generation+Teardown/10826 Not great, not terrible. Some interesting comments regarding digitiser and screen repair on that page, which imply the repair would involve a lot of glue and tricky removal. Hardest part might be to found a replacement screen at this point though.

Comment: @appleflapper you have an astonishing ability to look into my heart. Thanks for the ifixit link, that will help making a decision. Parts can be found (not sure about their quality).

Comment: Good to hear about the parts! Sorry I can't tell you more, I'm no repair expert. Good luck with the repair!